# Car on ferry between Gozo and Malta during the Christmas period

Tags: ferries, public-holidays, malta, christmas

I am travelling with a car from Malta to Gozo on the 28th of December and back on the 31st of December. According to the [ferry homepage](http://www.gozochannel.com/en/schedules.htm), it will be travelling normally on those days. I do not have any reservations for the ferry.

Should I worry about place availability? Or, since it will be low season, should there not be any issues getting onboard with a car?

Comment: @pnuts, thanks. I have corrected my question. I do not have any reservation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We did not have any issues getting on board. We arrived to take a ferry to Gozo on 28th around 10:00 and had to wait around 1.5 hours. On the way back on 31st we had to wait around 1 hour.

However, as far as we heard one might experienced longer waiting times sometimes, around 3-4 hours. This may be influenced by weather conditions or technical issues on ferries.